# imap function: passing a list and a another fixed string as argument (Python 3.7/3.8)

Tags: python, arguments

I want to use the `imap` function with several arguments. At the moment I am just using:

```
...   
p.imap(function, iterated_list_for_first_argument)
```

But I want to get it it to work with another pre-defined fixed string argument as 2nd argument.
Like this:

```
...   
p.imap(function, iterated_list_for_first_argument, second argument)
```

The `imap` function does not take two arguments if I understand it correctly.

Comment: I assume that you are talking about imap from python2 because in python3 is map

Comment: Use [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to add fixed arguments to functions.

Comment: @kederrac Python 3 still has imap function

Comment: @martineau Thank you. I got it to work with functools.partial().

Comment: asdfyxcvqwer: That's good to hear. Please [edit] your question and be more specific about what `imap()` function and version of Python you're using so it will be more helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `itertools.chain` to chain  `iterated_list_for_first_argument` with `second argument`, example:

```
from itertools import imap
from itertools import chain

iterated_list_for_first_argument = [[1,2], [1,2]]
second_argument = [[4]]
print list(imap(sum, chain(iterated_list_for_first_argument, second_argument)))
```

**output:**

```
[3, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying.
My first list is not nested tho. Its just `[1,2,3,4..]` and my second argument is fix. e.g. `[4]`
My desired output with sum function would look like: 5 , 6 , 7...

Comment: Solved the problem with `functools.partial()`, suggested by martineau